# align text bash script

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting, printf

I'm writing a script that will check the many applications services. I have the script looping through the services. Just looking for the best way to align the output text.

Here is the code:

```
services=(
     'MonTier-AppAdmin'
     'MonTier-Derby'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-1'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-2'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-3'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-4'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-1'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-2'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-3'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-4'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-1'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-2'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-3'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-4'
     'MonTier-HK-ESRetention'
     'MonTier-HK-WdpDeviceResources'
     'MonTier-HK-WdpServiceResources'
     'MonTier-HK-SyslogKeepalive'
     'MonTier-HK-WsmKeepalive'
     'MonTier-UI'
     'MonTier-Reports'
     'MonTier-AgentNode'
     'Kibana'
)

servicestat=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "$services" | wc -l)
for s in ${services[*]}
        do
                if [ "$servicestat" = "1" ]; then
                printf "$s status: \033[0;92mup\e[0m \n"
        else
                printf "$s status: \033[0;31mDOWN\e[0m \n"
        fi
done
```

This is the output I receive:

```
MonTier-AppAdmin status: up
MonTier-Derby status: up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-1 status: up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-2 status: up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-3 status: up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-4 status: up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-1 status: up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-2 status: up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-3 status: up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-4 status: up
MonTier-WsmAgent-1 status: up
MonTier-WsmAgent-2 status: up
MonTier-WsmAgent-3 status: up
MonTier-WsmAgent-4 status: up
MonTier-HK-ESRetention status: up
MonTier-HK-WdpDeviceResources status: up
MonTier-HK-WdpServiceResources status: up
MonTier-HK-SyslogKeepalive status: up
MonTier-HK-WsmKeepalive status: up
MonTier-UI status: up
MonTier-Reports status: up
MonTier-AgentNode status: up
Kibana status: up
```

How would I modify the script so the output looks like the following?

```
MonTier-AppAdmin status:                   up
MonTier-Derby status:                      up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-1 status:       up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-2 status:       up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-3 status:       up
MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-4 status:       up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-1 status:              up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-2 status:              up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-3 status:              up
MonTier-SyslogAgent-4 status:              up
MonTier-WsmAgent-1 status:                 up
MonTier-WsmAgent-2 status:                 up
MonTier-WsmAgent-3 status:                 up
MonTier-WsmAgent-4 status:                 up
MonTier-HK-ESRetention status:             up
MonTier-HK-WdpDeviceResources status:      up
MonTier-HK-WdpServiceResources status:     up
MonTier-HK-SyslogKeepalive status:         up
MonTier-HK-WsmKeepalive status:            up
MonTier-UI status:                         up
MonTier-Reports status:                    up
MonTier-AgentNode status:                  up
Kibana status:                             up
```

Comment: `column -t` might work here - it doesn't do exactly what you want but close

Comment: `column -t` actually does do exactly what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to keep the `:` in the final output then

```
column -t -s:
```

will do what you want, although with the escape codes it is a little fragile.

The correct thing IMHO to do is use a width specifier to printf. This also stops a bug if any of the services one day gets a `%` in the name.

Building on what @jesse_b says about pgrep, quoting etc, and using single quote wherever reasonable we get

```
services=(
     'MonTier-AppAdmin'
     'MonTier-Derby'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-1'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-2'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-3'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-4'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-1'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-2'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-3'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-4'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-1'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-2'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-3'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-4'
     'MonTier-HK-ESRetention'
     'MonTier-HK-WdpDeviceResources'
     'MonTier-HK-WdpServiceResources'
     'MonTier-HK-SyslogKeepalive'
     'MonTier-HK-WsmKeepalive'
     'MonTier-UI'
     'MonTier-Reports'
     'MonTier-AgentNode'
     'Kibana'
)
for s in "${services[@]}"; do
    printf '%-42s ' "$s status:"
    if pgrep "$s"; then
        printf '\033[0;92mup\e[0m \n'
    else
        printf '\033[0;31mDOWN\e[0m \n'
    fi
done
```

Here I hard code 42 for the width, but if the array of services changes then you could loop over the array and calculate the longest.

Answer (score 1):

Your script doesn't work the way you think it does.

First you should use `pgrep` instead of `ps -ef`, but if you do use `ps -ef` you need to `grep -v grep` **after** you grep for `service`.  However you need to grep for s inside the loop, otherwise you are only grepping for the first service once and not grepping for any others.

You should also use `"${services[@]}"` instead of `${services[*]}`

The following should work properly:

```
services=(
     'MonTier-AppAdmin'
     'MonTier-Derby'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-1'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-2'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-3'
     'MonTier-es-raw-trans-Nodes-4'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-1'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-2'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-3'
     'MonTier-SyslogAgent-4'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-1'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-2'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-3'
     'MonTier-WsmAgent-4'
     'MonTier-HK-ESRetention'
     'MonTier-HK-WdpDeviceResources'
     'MonTier-HK-WdpServiceResources'
     'MonTier-HK-SyslogKeepalive'
     'MonTier-HK-WsmKeepalive'
     'MonTier-UI'
     'MonTier-Reports'
     'MonTier-AgentNode'
     'Kibana'
)

for s in "${services[@]}"; do
    if pgrep -lf "$s" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        printf '%s status:?%b\n' "$s" '\033[0;92mup\e[0m'
    else
        printf '%s status:?%b\n' "$s" '\033[0;31mDOWN\e[0m'
    fi
done | column -s? -t
```

Here we are printing a `?` between `status:` and `up`/`DOWN` so that it can be used as a field separator for `column`

Comment: I also needed to change the second %s to %b to get the color to work, on my RHEL 7 box. 

However, the other issue I'm having is with pgrep. When I run the pgrep command outside of the script I see it's only showing the processes as java process (which they are), and I was grepping for the process conf file I see when issuing the ps command.

Comment: @dustin1530: In that case you can use `pgrep -lf`

Comment: When I use the `pgrep -lf` I get the PID and process name in my list too.

Comment: @dustin1530: Added redirection to `/dev/null`